# Display results of a query before query itself

Tags: php, mysql

I have this query:

```
<?php

echo $grand_total; // info on top of page

$getinfo = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sales");
while($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($getinfo)){
    $price = $rows['price']; // I want this to be display on top of my page before this query
    $quantity = $rows['quantity']; // I want this to be display on top of my page before this query
    $total = $price * $quantity;
    $grand_total += $total;
}

?>
```

I want to display the result of this query on the top of my page. Thanks in advance :)

[image]

Comment: write your query at the top of your page.

Comment: so whats the matter  place this query wherever you want to display your result....

Comment: how would you display data from DB without querying DB????

Comment: The arrangement should be like that. It's like you are writing from bottom to top. I'm working with a sales `report` that generates a computations. But the reports should be written from bottom to top.

Comment: Do you want to *reverse order* the query results? (ie. with [`ORDER BY`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sorting-rows.html)?)

Comment: @user2864740, is it possible? The `report's computations` I'm working with is reverse. It is written from bottom to top. Any remedy?

Comment: The language used is unclear as to the actual task. See the link in my previous comment and if it answers your question .. if not, I have no idea what is asked for ..

Comment: I am not sure why you would want to do what you are saying since `$fname` is in a loop and there is no indication of which `$fname` is the one you want to see at the top, but reversing as suggested by @user2864740 would make more sense.

Comment: Nah. Not `ORDER BY`.

Comment: @Rasclatt, I don't care the looping sir. It's just an example btw.

Comment: @ArchieZineg can you explain what are those *Reverse Computations* of yours? i have a feeling this is an xy issue...

Comment: Do you have a more realistic example? Possibly a javascript at the bottom of the page could populate a `<div>` (or other) placeholder at the top.

Comment: I will upload the image

Comment: Anything is possible, but not always possible with one language. PHP is not the be-all end-all. Try Javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Javascript will likely work.

```
<div id="grandtotal">0.00</div>
<?php
$getinfo = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sales");
while($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($getinfo)){
    $price = $rows['price']; // I want this to be display on top of my page before this query
    $quantity = $rows['quantity']; // I want this to be display on top of my page before this query
    $total = $price * $quantity;
    $grand_total += $total;
}

?>
<script>
// I am using jQuery here. Traditional js will work
$('#grandtotal').html('<?php echo $grand_total; ?>');
</script>
```

Comment: This is a very nice possible solution

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky, oh I guess egg don't became chicken if they are not yet hatched?

Comment: Well technically @Hanky웃Panky is correct. You can't get the results before you query it, but it's possible to show it after the fact. Note, a user who has turned off Javascript will have issues displaying it this way.

Comment: Since you asked, yes they don't. This answer does *not* mean that you will get the data before the query is executed. Initially the data will be 0 and once the query is executed then it will be filled up later by java script. If you like to time it use Firebug and notice that eggs will still need a process to hatch first. And i suggested in the last paragraph that you can fetch the data and then use it whenever you want later. This answer does exactly that, and its a good one.

Comment: Wow! works like a CHICKEN. Thanks for your EGGxample.

Comment: But the unfortunately, like I said. There's no EGG the will need to HATCHED here.

Comment: Since you have got a nice answer, let's leave it at that. Let's not take things personally. Examples are just examples, nothing more than that. Have a nice day :)

Comment: @Rasclatt, I don't said I want to get the results reversely. My title says `display`. Thanks btw :)

Comment: I'm just stocked here very long. Yeah you are right :)

Answer (score 6):

Before the eggs hatch, they remain eggs and not become chickens. You can't tell someone hey here is the chicken (already) which will be hatched from this following egg once the due process completes.

**TL;DR**

That is not possible.

**Food for thought**

Imagine there was a way you could do that, then why would you want the hen to sit on those eggs and wait for them to hatch? Why would you then execute the query and waste time if you had that data already?

**And Oh**

> The arrangement should be like that. It's like you are writing from bottom to top. I'm working with a sales report that generates a computations. But the reports should be written from bottom to top. –  Archie Zineg

Write a new web programming language that will do that.

**Now on to a solution**

You're looking at the problem and formulating a solution the wrong way. While it is surely possible that you want to fill the lower part of report first and then go from there to top but it does not mean that you cannot fetch the data beforehand. You can easily use a template and fill it up the way you want. You can easily generate/fetch this data from database at the top and not display it anywhere until you reach the point where you want to use it.

Comment: You're right. Maybe. But, my question is not about eggs and/or chicken.

Comment: I'm looking for an answer. If there is no possible answer, just say `it's not posible`. You're making this long.

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the comments and the other answer, you cannot echo something prior to actually retrieving it. you can however, do something like this if you will:

```
<?php
getFName(); //put this line at the top of your page

function getFName(){    
    $getinfo = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table");
    while($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($getinfo)){
        $fname = $rows['fname']; // I want this to be display on top of my page before this query
        $lname = $rows['lname']; // I want this to be display on top of my page before this query
    }
    echo $fname; 
}
?>
```

Comment: I am sorry to have to down-vote this answer but do you realize this call is a waste of that loop? It will only return the last row's fname value. Why loop over all the records and waste them then? Just do an `ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1` and that is not the expected output either. What if there were 1 million records and we looped over all of them just to read the last record?

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky you completely missed the point of my answer. this is not about loops and queries, this is about placement of the results on the page. you can retrieve them however you want.